# Verificar se uma data é válida ou não em C?

Tags: c, funções

Eu preciso verificar se uma data é válida ou não em C, e para isto terei uma função chamada `verificarData` que será passada para ela o input do usuário e irá verificar se é ou não uma data válida.

Mas estou em dúvida, pois terei que quebrar em pedaços esta `data` para verificar se ela contém  :

> 1. Se contém duas barras entre a data
> 2. Se o dia é entre 1 e 31.
> 3. Se o mês é entre 1 e 12.
> 4. Ano esta no intervalo entre 1900 e 2100
> 5. Se mês for 04, 06, 09 ou 11, dia pode ser no máximo 30;
> 6. Se mês for 02, dia pode ser no máximo 28;
> 7. Se ano for bissexto e mês for 02, dia pode ser no máximo 29.

Qual é melhor usar no caso ? Usar `vetor` ou até mesmo `char` e tentar quebrar a data e fazer as devidas verificações, e se posso usar com char, como quebrar ele em pedaços para verificar ?

Por exemplo, caso o usuário entre com o seguinte valor :

```
Input : 20/03/2009
```

Como posso quebrar para que fique, `20/`, `03/` e `2009` separados para que eu possa verificar ?

Preciso também verificar se o dia, mês e ano são numéricos, mas como estou colocando barras com números não consigo usar a função `isdigit` para verificar.

**Exemplo :**

```
if(isdigit(data)) {
printf("São numéricos.");
}
else {
printf("Não são numéricos.");
}
```

Mas ele retorna como que não são números mesmo o usuário colocando o dia, o mês e o ano com números, pois por causa das barras, ele retorna como se fosse uma string. Como posso verificar e retornar dizendo se são números ou não de forma correta ?

Comment: para cada um dos casos, qual o resultado esperado? Algum tipo de mensagem para o usuário ou são somente validações?

Comment: Somente validações, uma mensagem será disparada para o usuário somente se após verificar se é valido ou não a data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Por exemplo, caso o usuário entre com o seguinte valor :
>
> `Input : 20/03/2009`
>
> Como posso quebrar para que fique, `20/`, `03/` e `2009` separados para que eu possa verificar?

**Funções**

Utilize as funções abaixo.

- [`strtok`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html) - quebra uma string em tokens, dado um delimitador específico (use `/`).
- [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html) -
  converte uma string para um inteiro longo.
- [`strstr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strstr.html) - localiza a primeira ocorrência de uma substring específica em uma string (use `//`).
- [`isdigit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isdigit.html) - verifica se o caractere passado como argumento é um dígito.

**Lógica**

Base do código abaixo. Também veja funcionando online [aqui](https://repl.it/IqP1/5).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int verificarNumero(char *entrada) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; entrada[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (entrada[i] != '/' && !isdigit(entrada[i]))
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  return 1;
}

int verificarData(char *entrada)
{
  const char substring[3] = "//";

  if (strstr(entrada, substring) != NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  if (verificarNumero(entrada))
  {
    printf("São numéricos.\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Não são numéricos.\n");
    return 0;
  }

  int i = 0;
  long data[3];
  const char delimitador[2] = "/";
  char *token = strtok(entrada, delimitador);

  // Alimenta o vetor de inteiros
  while (token != NULL)
  {
    data[i++] = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
    token = strtok(NULL, delimitador);
  }

  // Realize suas validações. Se alguma não for atingida, retorne '0'

  printf("Dia: %d\n", data[0]);
  printf("Mes: %d\n", data[1]);
  printf("Ano: %d\n", data[2]);

  // Caso contrário, retorne '1'

  return 1;
}

int main()
{
  char str[80];

  printf("Digite uma data: ");
  gets(str);

  printf("%d\n", verificarData(str));

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, vou realizar as devidas modificações e retorno depois para lhe falar se funcionou ou não.

Comment: Não funciona o seu código, pelo menos não do jeito que eu queria, ele não quebra de vez a data, pois ao mostrar pelo printf ele mostra de forma errada a data.

Comment: Como assim, @Monteiro? Exemplo online [aqui](https://repl.it/IqP1/1), o que tem de errado?

Comment: Nesse seu novo exemplo online, ele funcionou sim, muito obrigado. Mas agora eu preciso verificar se realmente tem duas barras a data, por exemplo, com um if, se o usuário colocou somente uma barra na data então ele retorna 0 para o programa e se colocou duas, retorna 1.

Comment: @Monteiro atualizei a resposta e o exemplo online.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, funcionou certinho o seu código, e ainda por cima aprendi novas coisas em C, e já atualizei meu código aqui com os devidos if-else para fazer a verificação e funcionou. +1 e resposta certa também.

Comment: Uma ultima dúvida, como posso verificar se data é um número ou uma string ? Eu estou tentando usar isdigit mas como contém barras, ele retorna como falso o resultado e diz que não são números.

Comment: @Monteiro não sei se entendi direito. Pode dar um exemplo de entrada?

Comment: Tenho que verificar se o input do usuário é um número ou uma string. O dia, mês e ano precisam ser numéricos, e então, preciso fazer esta verificação. Vou colocar este exemplo do que eu quero na minha pergunta.

Comment: @Monteiro atualizei a resposta. `isdigit()` recebe apenas um caractere por vez. Você precisa acessar cada caractere da string para fazer a verificação, conforme demonstrei no exemplo.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado por tudo mesmo. Ali no !isdisgit(entrada[i]) é verificando se não é diferente certo ?

Comment: `!isdisgit(entrada[i])` é `true` quando `entrada[i]` **não** é um dígito, `false` quando for um dígito.

Comment: Tudo bem, entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação do código e pelo código em si, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score -2):

Ola

Eu fiz um pequeno exemplo Simples,de como validar dados usando if() 
O usuario faz o input, a funcao, verificardata verifica se os dados estao correctos;
Espero ter ajudado com um exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int dd, mm, yy;

    printf("Enter date (DD/MM/YYYY format): ");
    scanf_s("%d/%d/%d", &dd, &mm, &yy);

    //check year
    if (yy >= 1900 && yy <= 9999)
    {
        //check month
        if (mm >= 1 && mm <= 12)
        {
            //check days
            if ((dd >= 1 && dd <= 31) && (mm == 1 || mm == 3 || mm == 5 || mm == 7 || mm == 8 || mm == 10 || mm == 12))
                printf("Date is valid.\n");
            else if ((dd >= 1 && dd <= 30) && (mm == 4 || mm == 6 || mm == 9 || mm == 11))
                printf("Date is valid.\n");
            else if ((dd >= 1 && dd <= 28) && (mm == 2))
                printf("Date is valid.\n");
            else if (dd == 29 && mm == 2 && (yy % 400 == 0 || (yy % 4 == 0 && yy % 100 != 0)))
                printf("Date is valid.\n");
            else
                printf("Day is invalid.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Month is not valid.\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Year is not valid.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá, mas aonde esta a função ai ? Terei que pegar este código e passar para a função então certo ? E deixar somente no main o input do usuário. Mas ainda preciso verificar se a data contém barras.

Answer (score -2):

Função para validar uma data no formato dd/mm/yy:
A string que contém a data terá um tamanho fixo sempre que é 11 contando com o caracter de controle '\0', tudo que se precisa fazer é converter os carcteres que representam o dia/ o mês e o ano e verificar os seus limites válidos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int valid(char *date)
{
int tmp=0,tmp1=0,tmp2=0,flag=0;
if(strlen(date)<=10){
tmp=(date[0]-'0')*10+(date[1] - '0');
if(tmp > 0 && tmp <32) flag++;
tmp1=(date[3]-'0')*10+(date[4]-'0');
if(tmp1 > 0 && tmp1 <13) flag++;
tmp2=(((date[6]-'0')*10+(date[7]-'0'))*10+(date[8]-'0'))*10+(date[9]-'0');
if(tmp2 > 2000) flag++;
}
return flag==3 ? 1 : 0;

}
  main()
  {
  char xx[20];
  gets(xx);
  printf("data valida %d?", valid(xx));
  }
```